# implement music with SharedPreferences in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, togglebutton, audio-player, android-music-player

i'm building an app in android, i've three classes right now, one Main, one Music and one Setting. i'm trying to put music in my app, so that when i exit the app it'll stop. i've done that part.

i also have a toggle button in the setting class, which controls the music on/off, and i'm using SharedPreferences for the app to remember if the music is off or on. everything work when i enter the app and stay there, the off state really turn off the music and the on state turn her on, but the problem is when i exit and re-enter the Main class start playing music again. is there a way to check if the toggle button is checked in the Main class? i dont find any...

other problem, how can i mute the music when the phone is in mute state? i looked at switch method in this site but it didnt work. any help will be great!

here are the classes:

Main-

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Music.play(this, R.raw.pirates);
}

public void setting_onclick(View view) {
       Intent i = new Intent("net.lirazarviv.Setting");
       startActivity(i);
   }

@Override
  protected void onPause() {
    if (this.isFinishing()){ //basically BACK was pressed from this activity
      Music.stoping();

    }
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
      ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
      if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
        Music.stoping();
      }
    }
    super.onPause();
  }
}
```

Music-

```
public class Music {
private static MediaPlayer mp = null;

public static void play(Context context, int resource) {
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, resource);
         mp.setLooping(true);
         mp.start();
      }

public static void stop(Context context) { 
      if (mp != null) {
         mp.stop();
         mp.pause();
         mp.release();
         mp = null;
      }
   }


public static void playing() {
        mp.start();
}

public static void stoping() {
         mp.pause();

}
}
```

Setting-

```
public class Setting extends Activity {
ToggleButton Button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    addListenerOnButton();
    loadPrefs();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    Button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.MusicIconSelector);
    Button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Music.stoping();
                savePrefs("Button",true);
            }
            else { 
                Music.playing();
                savePrefs("Button",false);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void loadPrefs() {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            boolean cbValue = sp.getBoolean("Button", false);
            if(cbValue){
                Button.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                Button.setChecked(false);
            }
        }


private void savePrefs(String key, boolean value) {
            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putBoolean(key, value);
            edit.commit();
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences` you can use [Context.getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). By using this you can read write to same shared preferences from any component. For Eample

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

you can access the shared preference by the `name` from any activity.

Comment: how do i access the Shared preference from the main activity? i didnt get that part..

Comment: i tried to add this to the main class:

SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("ButtonData", MODE_PRIVATE);
  boolean cbValue = sp.getBoolean("ButtonData", false);
        if(cbValue){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Silent Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
         Music.play(this, R.raw.pirates);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Music Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

but now when i'm in Silent Mode the Setting class not working, and when i'm in Music Mode it does..